# How to provide selected rows to cgridview to display and at same time provide search for columns

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii

Here i am using CActiveDataProvider to pass the selected rows by giving condition and in the view i am displaying in CGridView the columns working fine but at the same time i should provide the search for the columns I am unable to provide the search can any one help. here is my sample code

### controller code

```
public function actionShow($id) 
{
    $model=new StudentResult('search');

    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['StudentResult']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['StudentResult'];

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('StudentResult', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>"profileId=$id",
            ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20,
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('show',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));

}
```

### view code

```
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
'model'=>$model,
 )); ?>
 </div><!-- search-form -->

<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'student-result-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'moduleCode',
    'moduleTitle',
    'moduleCredits',
    'grade',
    'creditsObtain',
    'semester',
    /*
    'points',
    'profileId',

    'createdOn',
    'lastModifiedOn',
    'lastModifiedBy',
    */
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

so in view i am displaying the data by giving the 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider so values are displaying correctly but the search is not working if i provide 'dataProvider' => $model->search(); the whole values are displaying and search is working

Comment: Elaborate little about selected rows. User have to select the row or you decide to show the particular row?

Comment: admin will click on the id link so that id will be collected in the show method and by using that id it will display the particular rows

Answer (score 1):

Here you can pass your selected row to the action you want.

```
   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array('id' =>'list-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->search(),
        'filter' =>$dataProvider, 
        'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'moduleCode',
        'moduleTitle',
        'moduleCredits',
        'grade',
        'creditsObtain',
        'semester',
         'action'=>array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'header' => 'Edit',
            'template' => '{Edit}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'Edit' =>array(
                'label' => 'Edit',
            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()>request>baseUrl.'path/to/your/image',// you can use other options
                 'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/controller/action/id/".someencryption-to-hide-id($data->id))',),             
'visible' => TRUE,      ),
           ),
        ), )); ?>
```

Your controller action goes like this:

```
public function actionYourAction() {
        $dataProvider = new ModelName('search');
        $dataProvider -> unsetAttributes();
        // clear any default values
        if (isset($_GET['ModelName'])) {
            $dataProvider -> attributes = $_GET['ModelName'];
        }
        $this -> render('viewPage', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider, ));

    }
```

And Model Criteria will be:

```
 public function search()
    {
        $criteria -> compare('id', $this -> id);
        ...
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria' => $criteria, ));
    }
```

Let me know am i getting you right.